# Variable in method

Tags: ruby

I have something like this:

```
case method
when :get    
   HTTParty.get(configuration.endpoint)
when :post
   HTTParty.post(configuration.endpoint)
when :put
   HTTParty.put(configuration.endpoint)
end
```

How to do this?

```
HTTParty.{method}(configuration.endpoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `public_send` ruby method

```
HTTParty.public_send(method)
```

or with argument(s)

```
HTTParty.public_send(method, arg1, arg2)
```

Documentation of public_send method [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send)